# How to copy all contents of a particular worksheet from multiple Workbooks in a directory and populate into activeworkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a unique problem set. I have multiple Workbooks in a directory having worksheets with same name as "Allocation". I need to search through every rows in the worksheets("Allocation") to find text (under column N ) "In-Progress" or "Failed" and iteratively copy the entire row from the respective worksheets ("Allocation") by  going through multiple workbooks present in the folder and finally paste the rows into my active worksheet("Master").

The totals rows in each worksheet is not more than 500

I am new to VBA, and below code from web partially helped me .Need a help or way forward to tackle this problem.

I tried copying all worksheets in the multiple workbooks and then merged it to apply the search on the merged rows in the master worksheet . The code ran into Overflow error and Takes ages to finally do so .

```
Sub test()

    Dim MyFile As String, MyFiles As String, FilePath As String
    Dim erow As Long
    '~~> Put additional variable declaration
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet

    FilePath = "H:\Alloc\"
    MyFiles = "H:\Alloc\*.xlsm"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFiles)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    '~~> Set your declared variables
    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook 'if you want to consolidate files in this workbook
    Set wsMaster = wbMaster.Sheets("ALLAllocation") 'replace Sheet1 to suit

    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        'Debug.Print MyFile
        If MyFile <> "Anup_Allocation - Copy.xlsm" Then
            '~~> Open the file and at the same time, set your variable
            Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=FilePath & MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)
            Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets("Allocation") 'I used index, you said there is only 1 sheet
            '~~> Now directly work on your object
            With wsMaster
                erow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get the last row
                '~~> Copy from the file you opened
                wsTemp.Range("A2:N200").copy 'you said this is fixed as well
                '~~> Paste on your master sheet
                .Range("A" & erow).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
            '~~> Close the opened file
            wbTemp.Close False 'set to false, because we opened it as read-only
            Set wsTemp = Nothing
            Set wbTemp = Nothing
        End If
        '~~> Load the new file
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be faster than your current approach, and it will only copy the rows with "In-Progress" or "Failed":

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim MyFile As String, MyFiles As String, FilePath As String, MyCriteria As String
    Dim x As Long, i As Long, NFiles As Long, j As Long
    Dim arr As Variant, arrTemp As Variant

    '~~> Put additional variable declaration
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wsMaster As Worksheet, wsTemp As Worksheet

    FilePath = "H:\Alloc\"
    MyFiles = "H:\Alloc\*.xlsm"
    MyFile = Dir(MyFiles)
    NFiles = 10 'this could be counted using FSO

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    '~~> Set your declared variables
    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook 'if you want to consolidate files in this workbook
    Set wsMaster = wbMaster.Sheets("ALLAllocation") 'replace Sheet1 to suit

    'this will dimension an array as large as 500 rows multiplied for NFiles and with many columns as the master sheet
    ReDim arr(1 To 500 * NFiles, 1 To wsMaster.UsedRange.Columns.Count)
    x = 1 'initialize the main array row counter
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        'Debug.Print MyFile
        If MyFile <> "Anup_Allocation - Copy.xlsm" Then
            '~~> Open the file and at the same time, set your variable
            Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FilePath & MyFile, ReadOnly:=True)
            'insert the whole data from the sheet inside the temporal array
            arrTemp = wbTemp.Sheets("Allocation").UsedRange.Value
            '~~> Close the opened file
            wbTemp.Close
            Set wbTemp = Nothing
            For i = 2 To UBound(arrTemp)
                MyCriteria = arrTemp(i, 14) 'this is the column N
                If MyCriteria = "In-Progress" Or MyCriteria = "Failed" Then 'if the criteria is meet
                    'loop through all the columns to add the row on your main array
                    For j = 1 To UBound(arrTemp, 2)
                        arr(x, j) = arrTemp(i, j)
                    Next j
                    x = x + 1 'add a counter to your main array row
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        '~~> Load the new file
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    With wsMaster
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find the next available row on the master sheet
        .Range("A" & i, .Cells(UBound(arr) + i, UBound(arr, 2))).Value = arr 'paste the array to the master sheet
        'delete the most likely extra rows inserted by the array
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'find the next available row on the master sheet
        .Rows(i & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

This might fail if you have fewer columns on your master sheet than the temporal workbooks have or if you don't change the 10 on `NFile` and you have more than 10 files... Check how to count the files in a folder using FSO (FileSystemObject).